# How to create balanced instead of priority logic?

Tags: switch-statement, logic, verilog

How to create balanced logic (`case`) instead of priority (`if .. else`) for the following case?

I know I could get balanced logic when I change following priority logic

```
if(a == 2'b00) out = 1;
else if(a == 2'b01) out = 4'b0010;
else if(a == 2'b10) out = 4'b0100;
else if(a == 2'b11) out = 4'b1000;
```

To

```
case(a)
    2'b00: out = 1;
    2'b01: out = 2;
    2'b10: out = 4;
    2'b11: out = 8;
endcase
```

But how can I get balanced logic if the priority logic is this?

```
if(a) out = 1;
else if(b) out = 4'b0010;
else if(c) out = 4'b0100;
else if(d) out = 4'b1000;
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
case (1'b1)

  a:out = 1;
  b:out = 4'b0010;
  c:out = 4'b0100;
  d:out = 4'b1000;

endcase
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418636/case-statement-in-verilog) for concerns about priority.

Comment: So is a, b, c, d could be any bit?

Comment: @Regan: I assumed they are 1-bit long. You could have a case where a, b, c, d are longer. In that case, they should be at least as long as the case value.